# yum install apt error

Tags: linux, yum, apt

I got below errors when installing apt. 
It seems I am missing require packges.

```
Error: Package: apt-0.5.15lorg3.94a-5.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               Requires: librpm-4.4.so()(64bit)
    Error: Package: apt-0.5.15lorg3.94a-5.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               Requires: librpmio-4.4.so()(64bit)
    Error: Package: apt-0.5.15lorg3.94a-5.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               Requires: librpmdb-4.4.so()(64bit)
```

Anyone encountered similar things before?
Do I need to install the missing package one by one?

Thanks.

```
[root@db8 src]# uname -r
2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64




[root@db8 src]# yum install apt
 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.vipernetworksystems.com
 * extras: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.linux.duke.edu
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package apt.x86_64 0:0.5.15lorg3.94a-5.el5.rf will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: librpmio-4.4.so()(64bit) for package: apt-0.5.15lorg3.94a-5.el5.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libreadline.so.5()(64bit) for package: apt-0.5.15lorg3.94a-5.el5.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librpm-4.4.so()(64bit) for package: apt-0.5.15lorg3.94a-5.el5.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librpmdb-4.4.so()(64bit) for package: apt-0.5.15lorg3.94a-5.el5.rf.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package apt.x86_64 0:0.5.15lorg3.94a-5.el5.rf will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: librpmio-4.4.so()(64bit) for package: apt-0.5.15lorg3.94a-5.el5.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librpm-4.4.so()(64bit) for package: apt-0.5.15lorg3.94a-5.el5.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librpmdb-4.4.so()(64bit) for package: apt-0.5.15lorg3.94a-5.el5.rf.x86_64
---> Package compat-readline5.x86_64 0:5.2-17.1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: apt-0.5.15lorg3.94a-5.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: librpm-4.4.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: apt-0.5.15lorg3.94a-5.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: librpmio-4.4.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: apt-0.5.15lorg3.94a-5.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: librpmdb-4.4.so()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Why are you installing apt on a RedHat Entreprise Linux ? BTW, this question is not for stackoverflow, but for superuser.

Comment: because I want to install php5-dev and php mongo driver.

Comment: the solution is to first: yum install php to install php5 second:yum install php-devel to install phpize third: sudo pecl install mongo to install php mongo driver anyway, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install/Update rpm-libs-4.4 first. If not found in rpmforge release repo, try epel release.

Comment: the solution is to first: yum install php to install php5 second:yum install php-devel to install phpize third: sudo pecl install mongo to install php mongo driver anyway, Thanks for the help